# unique STL container with special ordering

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a need for a STL container which is capable of:

**1) only storing unique items**

**2) has a guaranteed order based on when item was added to the container**

So, if I add items A, B, and C to my container in that order,

**A** will always be accessible via: `myItems().begin()` or `myItems[0]`

**B** will always be accessible via:
`myItems.begin() + 1` or `myItems[1]`

**C** will always be accessible via:
`myItems.begin() + 2` or `myItems[2]`

I am currently using an `unordered_set` which does not fulfill need #2. If I use a regular `set`, I can specify a less than function for ordering but the ordering may change as new items are added to the container.

Using a regular `set`, if I insert a new item D which is less than A, A will no longer be accessible via `myItems.begin()`. I could be wrong but that is my understanding of how set ordering works.

If I use a `list`, I can enforce the unique aspect by calling `list::unique()` after inserting every new item:

```
myList.sort();
myList.unique();
```

or I could use `std::find` with a list or a vector and manually enforce the unique aspect:

```
iter = std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), item);

//Only add item if not already in list/vector...
if(iter == myList.end())
{
    myList.push_back(item);
}
```

Is there a better container/solution for my particular needs?

Comment: How did you arrive at these requirements? They seem unorthodox to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Looks like the building blocks for a FIFO cache to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such container in the STL, although you can implement one with the existing containers by mixing a `std::set`/`std::unordered_set` (to check for uniqueness) and a `std::deque` (or any other sequence container) for the ordering.

Boost has multiindex containers that already do this for you if you can use it and want to take a look.

Comment: Would using both look something like this? 1) Insert item into `set/unordered_set` 2) Check the returned `pair` of set::insert() to see if item already existed in set 3) If item didn't already exist in set, add to deque/vector. 4) Now I have a manually constructed `deque\vector` of unique items with the correct ordering

Comment: @user974967: Correct. You also need to track deletions of elements so that they happen from both views of the container. Depending on your usage pattern that might be simple (i.e. if you always work on the ordered sequence, then removal is a binary search on the `std::set` or a O(N) lookup in the `std::unordered_set`

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use **std::vector** or **std::deque** in that case. **std::list** is not good solution since you need to access elements by index (lists have O(n) complexity on this operation). **std::deque** can be somewhat slower than vector for index access since it manages memory with chunks. But, if you have frequent/scattered inserts, deque can be better.

If you need to preserve order in which elements added, you cant do **sort/unique**; so this task requires uniqueness constraint which can be done using **std::set** or **unordered_map**.